# Determine the number of rows with NAs

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame as follows:

```
     col1   col2    col3
 1    23    17      NA
 2    55    NA      NA
 3    24    12      13
 4    34    23      12
```

I'm interested in finding the number of rows in col2 and col3 with NAs.

I was surprised that the following code only gave me 4 instead of 2:

```
numNAs <- rowSums(is.na(all[,2:3]))
```

Please help.

Comment: You want the number of rows with `NA` in or the number of `NA` in each row of columns `2` and `3`?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50919195/7936744) to a similar question for a comprehensive list of the ways to examine NAs in a dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="     col1   col2    col3
 1    23    17      NA
 2    55    NA      NA
 3    24    12      13
 4    34    23      12", header=TRUE)
```

This gives the number of rows that contain any `NA` values in column 2 or 3:

```
sum(colSums(is.na(DF[,2:3])) > 0)
[1] 2
```

Comment: `complete.cases` is useful here. `sum(!complete.cases(DF[, 2:3]))`

Answer (score 3):

Another short solution:

```
> sum(!complete.cases(dat[-1]))
[1] 2
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
data <- read.table(text='col1   col2    col3
    23    17      NA
    55    NA      NA
    24    12      13
    34    23      12', header=T)

sum(apply(is.na(data[, -1]), 1, any))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test <- read.table(textConnection("     col1   col2    col3
1    23    17      NA
2    55    NA      NA
3    24    12      13
4    34    23      12"))

> table(test$col2,useNA="ifany")

  12   17   23 <NA> 
   1    1    1    1 
> table(test$col3,useNA="ifany")

  12   13 <NA> 
   1    1    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution adding columns 2 and 3:

```
> sum(is.na(all[,"col2"] + all[,"col3"]))
[1] 2
```