# How to simply count number of rows with NAs - R

Tags: r, dataframe, row, na

I'm trying to compute the number of rows with NA of the whole df as I'm looking to compute the % of rows with NA over the total number of rows of the df.

I have already have seen this post: [Determine the number of rows with NAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138927/determine-the-number-of-rows-with-nas) but it just shows a specific range of columns.

Comment: Use the same answer as the post that you cite, but remove the column restriction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

tl;dr: row wise, you'll want `sum(!complete.cases(DF))`,  or, equivalently, `sum(apply(DF, 1, anyNA))`

There are a number of different ways to look at the number, proportion or position of `NA` values in a data frame:

Most of these start with the logical data frame with `TRUE` for every `NA`, and `FALSE` everywhere else. For the base dataset `airquality`

```
is.na(airquality)
```

There are 44 `NA` values in this data set

```
sum(is.na(airquality))
# [1] 44
```

You can look at the total number of `NA` values per row or column:

```
head(rowSums(is.na(airquality)))
# [1] 0 0 0 0 2 1
colSums(is.na(airquality))
#   Ozone Solar.R    Wind    Temp   Month     Day 
 37       7       0       0       0       0
```

You can use `anyNA()` in place of `is.na()` as well:

```
# by row
head(apply(airquality, 1, anyNA))
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
sum(apply(airquality, 1, anyNA))
# [1] 42


# by column
head(apply(airquality, 2, anyNA))
#   Ozone Solar.R    Wind    Temp   Month     Day 
#    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
sum(apply(airquality, 2, anyNA))
# [1] 2
```

`complete.cases()` can be used, but only row-wise:

```
sum(!complete.cases(airquality))
# [1] 42
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the number of rows with NA values, as I already did with just NA values.

Comment: I'm getting there... give me a bit :)

Comment: There, should be a little more comprehensive than just the one-liner for the specific question

Comment: FYI, you should use `apply(is.na(airquality), 1, any))` for much better performance results -- type conversion to lists using `apply` is always slow.

Comment: @RobertKrzyzanowski In my experience and tests, `anyNA` was superior to `any(is.na())`, but it's been a while since I've run them...

Comment: @RobertKrzyzanowski ahh.. I think i see what you're saying now. I'll test it

Answer (score 2):

From the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138927/determine-the-number-of-rows-with-nas):

```
DF <- read.table(text="     col1   col2    col3
 1    23    17      NA
 2    55    NA      NA
 3    24    12      13
 4    34    23      12", header=TRUE)
```

You can check which rows have at least one NA:

```
(which_nas <- apply(DF, 1, function(X) any(is.na(X))))
#    1     2     3     4 
# TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

And then count them, identify them or get the ratio:

```
## Identify them
which(which_nas)
# 1 2 
# 1 2 

## Count them
length(which(which_nas))
#[1] 2

## Ratio
length(which(which_nas))/nrow(DF)
#[1] 0.5
```